# Go To Last Page arrows not working on list views

Tags: permissions, list-view

On Contact and Account List views, the double arrows at the bottom of the page are grayed out on all of my sandboxes and prod.  How do I turn this back on.  I've looked at profiles, and object permissions as well as User Interface to no avail.

[image]

Comment: What's your page size?   It seem odd that you were able to set it to 45...   Also, is this a custom VisualForce page?

Comment: The double arrows are available when retrieving 2000 or less records. It's possible because you're getting too many records, Salesforce doesn't 'know' where the end is. Guessing a little bit here but try filtering to get less than 2000 records and see if they appear then?

Comment: This isn't a visualforce page, but it is wierd that I filtered to only show a couple hundred records, and now it's visible.  Thanks James and @Poet for your responses.

Comment: @Poet -- looks like you got the answer - please post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double arrows are available when retrieving 2000 or less records. It's possible because you're getting too many records, Salesforce doesn't 'know' where the end is.

Guessing a little bit here but try filtering to get less than 2000 records and see if they appear then? That might just confirm it.